Is it possible to extract all product columns except for one?
I currently extract all product data in CSV format.
There is also the option to select columns too.
However, I sometimes want to exclude just one particular column, or maybe even a few others.
Naturally, I would write a SQL query to extract everything except for the column(s) in question.
However, the products page doesn't allow SQL functionality, instead only allowing me to select the column(s) that I wish to extract.
Rather than clicking on 49 out of 50 columns (I'm unsure of the exact number of columns - 50 is just an example), is there a way I can simply list the column(s) that I wish to ignore?
To make things clearer, if I were to do this in SQL I would write something like this:
SELECT *
EXCEPT (specific_column)
FROM products;

Thank you.

By using Product Import Export for WooCommerce plugin you can skip/Choose column to include or exclude and export the products data.

if you do not mind using third-party tools especially if you need it for several times, you can use Store Manager for WooCommerce (has free trial), there's a possibility to select the needed columns or unmap needless ones at the step of import
